# PHP command line interface passing in multiple files

Tags: php, command-line

I'm familiar with the basic of CLI and $argv array with php.
Example:

```
<?php // test.php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```

> $php test.php datafile.txt 10 100

will produce:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "test.php"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "datafile.txt"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "100"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is pass all files in a directory *.txt to php.  Is there way I can do `$php test.php *.txt` and have all the filenames stored in an array?

Edit:  for the solution I just use the glob function

```
<?php
$files = glob($argv[1]);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). I assume you would just call it for every argument, using the argument as the parameter and merge the resultant arrays using array merge.

Comment: I'll look into glob.  It's looks like a possible solution